# what "coming to" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Since then, diplomacy has evolved greatly, **coming to** mean different things, to different people, at different times, ranging from the elegant (‘the management of relations between independent states by the process of negotiations’: Harold Nicolson) to the inelegant (‘the art of saying nice “doggie” until you can find a rock’: Wynn Catlin).
Whatever one’s definition, few could doubt that the course and consequences of the major events of modern international diplomacy have shaped and changed the global world in which we live.
It is the purpose of this book to introduce the general reader to the subject and study of diplomacy, from an historical perspective.

does "coming to" mean "going to mean different thing for different people, happening" ?

Comment: It means that during the course of its history, it has meant different things, to different people...

Comment: A common example/idiom of this term is: "What has the world *come to*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"coming to mean different things": evolving over time to mean different things.

Comment: Good answer. Generally come is used when the direction is towards where the speaker is. Go when the direction is away from the speaker.  Diplomacy has developed over centuries coming to us today from the past, improved along the way.  That's why 'coming to" is used in the sentence.